# Как получить все функции с приоритетом '1' прицепленные к хуку 'wp_head' ('_wp_render_title_tag', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'noindex' и т. д.)?

Tags: wordpress

Как получить (перебрать в цикле для отключения ненужных) все функции с приоритетом `'1'` прицепленные к хуку `'wp_head'` (`'_wp_render_title_tag'`, `'wp_enqueue_scripts'`, `'noindex'` и т. д.)?

Получить надо именно автоматически, чтобы после каждой новой версии WordPress не отслеживать, не засунули ли в приоритет `'1'` ещё чего-нибудь.

Что-то типа:

```
$array_priority_1 = [];

if (doing_action('wp_head')) {
  // Здесь получаем и перебираем все функции связанные с 'wp_head'
  // и сразу проверяем у них приоритет '1'?
  // и подходящие помещаем в массив '$array_priority_1'
  //
  // ...не знаю как их получить и проверить на приоритет
}
```

А здесь уже перебираем наш готовый массив:

```
foreach ($array_priority_1 as ...
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Я так и не понял из ваших двух вопросов - зачем вам удалять, например, `_wp_render_title_tag`? Вам в заголовке страницы активно мешает тег `<title>...</title>`? Можете пояснить,чем именно?

Answer (score 0):

Там не всё так просто. Все хуки (акции и фильтры) хранятся в глобальном массиве `$wp_filter`. Выглядит это примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видим, коллбэки (вызовы) распределены в массив с ключами по приоритетам, а сами вызовы могут быть описаны либо строкой (`_wp_render_title_tag`), либо массивом, как `WPML_SEO_HeadLangs`, где первый элемент - класс (`SitePress`), а второй - имя функции в нём (`head_langs`).

Вот рабочий код, который удаляет акцию или фильтр:

```
/**
 * Remove action or filter from plugin.
 *
 * @param string $class_name Class name enqueueing the action.
 * @param null $action_name
 */
function remove_plugin_action( $class_name, $action_name = null ) {
    global $wp_filter;

    if ( null === $action_name ) {
        $action_name = current_action();
    }

    /** @var $hooks WP_Hook */
    $hooks = $wp_filter[ $action_name ];

    $callbacks = $hooks->callbacks;

    foreach ( $callbacks as $priority => $actions ) {
        foreach ( $actions as $action ) {
            $function = $action['function'];
            if ( is_array( $function ) && ( get_class( $function[0] ) === $class_name ) ) {
                remove_action( $action_name, $function, $priority );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Рабочий пример использования:

```
function action_google_maps_script() {
    if ( ! ( is_page_template( 'templ-contact.php' ) ) ) {
        remove_plugin_action( 'PageSpeed_Optimization' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'action_google_maps_script', 0 );
```

В данном примере на событии 'wp_enqueue_scripts' с приоритетом 0 вызывается функция `action_google_maps_script()` в которой проверяется шаблон страницы и при совпадении удаляются все акции 'wp_enqueue_scripts', созданные классом `PageSpeed_Optimization` (с любым приоритетом).

Непонятно, чем вам так не понравились акции с приоритетом именно 1. А с приоритетами 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 99, 101 (как на картинке) - вам не беспокоят?

Я уже писал в предыдущем вашем вопросе - не надо бездумно удалять всё подряд. Вы просто сломаете функционал ядра.

Аккуратное использование приведённой в данном ответе функции поможет вам удалить те акции или фильтры, которые реально мешают выполнению вашего кода.

Comment: Благодарю, Вас!

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезным, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу, чтобы помочь людям, ищущим ответ на похожий вопрос.